# React - accessing ref from "unrelated" component

Tags: reactjs, ref, siblings, use-ref, react-forwardref

I have a React App with this sort of structure:

```
const App = () => {
    return (
        <AnimatedBackground/>        
        <HomePage/>
    )
}
    
const AnimatedBackground = () => {
    return (
        <canvas>
            // consume ref here v
            <BackgroundParticles/>
        </canvas>        
    )
}

const HomePage = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <SearchBar/>  // <- reference this component
            <OtherStuff/>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Until now `SearchBar` and `BackgroundParticles` were completely independent from each other, but I have decided to make the animated `BackgroundParticles` interact with (bounce off) `SearchBar`, for which I need the latter's measures and coordinates (`ref.current?.getBoundingClientRect()`).

Since the common parent (`App`) is several levels up, what is the proper way of accessing a reference to `SearchBar` from `BackgroundParticles`? Do I have to use `forwardRef` at all from `App` or do I drill the ref down to `SearchBar` as a regular prop? How would I consume the `SearchBar` ref from `BackgroundParticles` in the other branch? With a context.provider from App?

Cheers =)

Comment: Could you not just define the ref in the common parent and then inherit it in both components? Any change to ref.current would then be accessible to both components (if I'm not wrong). If you don't want to prop drill, you could have a look at using React Context (https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html). You may have to use forwardRef? But you might be able to get away with just passing it as a prop (just ensure your prop is named anything except 'ref' (or 'key' obviously).

Comment: This could be XY problem. Why exactly a ref is needed for? Couldn't Searchbar give away all relevant info to the outside? This ia what global state is for.ii

Comment: Don't I need a ref to access the component in the DOM in order to extract its coordinates and measures with `ref.current?.getBoundingClientRect()`? As for `useState`, I was conflicted about whether I needed it or not since components get resized automatically without having to store their state at all, I assumed it was all done under the hood. But yeah, part of my doubt is whether I should use createRef or just useState to store/pass down the extracted measures.

Comment: In the end I just created a `useState` in the App component and passed it to a global context. `SearchBar` imports with useContext the state setter function and `BackgroundParticles` consumes the modified state value.

Doesn't feel very clean but I guess that's the way.

Comment: Looks fine to me, that's how I'd expect it to be implemented